# How I can append "PHP echo" code in html <div>

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, append

I am developing a chat between 2 users. I store the messages in a MySQL database and on chat box page I call AJAX each 2 seconds to get new messages.
All works fine with plain text messages but now I need to allow users to send also files.

I append the new messages using:

```
$("#chat_container").append(`                                                
    <div class="message-bubble ${clasa} ">
        <div class="message-bubble-inner">
            <div class="message-text">${output_response.Result[i].out_Message}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
`);
```

My chat_container is:

```
<div id = "chat_container" class="message-content-inner">
</div>
```

${output_response.Result[i].out_Message} is the plain text that I store in mysql databased. For files I am uploading them to server using a php script that returns me the path and then i store the path as a message in database like:

```
<a href='upload/1619779744.jpg'>Picture</a>
```

Because of this the user will see that the message is actually a link and when he clicks on it he goes to
https://server/upload/1619779744.jpg and he downloads the picture which is good.

The problem is that I want to add some security to the site and not show direct path to files in link.

For this I implemented this class https://github.com/sujeetkrsingh/Secure-Download-Url
It works good in a separated file using:

```
<div class="message-text"><a href="<?php echo $encrypturl->getDownloadLink('upload/1619779744.jpg'); ?>">AWS11 Logo</a></div>
```

This will return to user the link https://server.com/download.php?f=2f4df28349d56457b897f2ed3966799735564add3bef41c0 which hides the actual path of the file.

The problem is that if I store in database `<a href="<?php echo $encrypturl->getDownloadLink('upload/1619779744.jpg'); ?>">AWS11 Logo</a>` instead of  `<a href='upload/1619779744.jpg'>Picture</a>` the link of the file is
`https://server/%3C?php%20echo%20$encrypturl-%3EgetDownloadLink(%27upload/1619779744.jpg%27);%20?%3E` which is wrong.

So the question is how I can append HTML + PHP code using jquery append function?
In my chat file I included the class in the beginning of file using `<?php require_once("EncryptUrl.php"); $encrypturl=new EncryptUrl(); ?>` and I renamed the file from .html to .php

Comment: _“which is wrong”_ - it’s wrong, because you _made_ it wrong. You used `<?php echo` in a place, where you should have used _string concatenation_ instead.

Comment: I would try to put in DB not `$encrypturl->getDownloadLink('upload/1619779744.jpg')`, but the result of its execution. So you might store `<a href='download.php?f=2f4df28349d56457b897f2ed3966799735564add3bef41c0'>Picture</a>` in your DB instead of `<a href="<?php echo $encrypturl->getDownloadLink('upload/1619779744.jpg'); ?>">`. Does it make sense?

Comment: what do you mean @CBroe? @Ihor I will try to see if this will work, i hope the download link remains the same.